# Can we have custom messages in hive for a particular query like create database or create table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a requirement wherein i want to know whether the database already exists.In this case, my database **hivedb** already exists.When i try to run the below 2 statements then first statement is fine but i want the second statement to say that the db will not be created as it already exists.Can we have custom messages for that?

`hive> CREATE DATABASE hivedb;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Database hivedb already exists
hive> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS hivedb;
OK
Time taken: 0.025 seconds`